# How to access props from within view method of custom react native module

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to write a native module to wrap an iOS component.
From within my `- (UIView *)view` method I want to be able to access the props that were provided to my component.

I can't seem to find any way to do it.

I've tried using `RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY` and setting a property from within my Obj-C code, but the property seems to be set after my `- (UIView *)view` method has been called and rendered.

The reason I need to do this is that I am trying to render an ApplePay button from within my view method, and I want to be able to change the type of the button by setting a prop on my component. E.g:

```
- (UIView *)view
{
  PKPaymentButtonType type = [self.aPropOnMyObject isEqualToString:@"setup"] ? PKPaymentButtonTypeSetUp : PKPaymentButtonTypeBuy;
  return [PKPaymentButton buttonWithType:type style:PKPaymentButtonStyleWhiteOutline];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method on your view this way:

```
RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY(aPropOnMyObject, NSString, PKPaymentButtonType)
{
  // view is what you returned from `view` method, 
  // json is the NString value from React-Native
  [view setButtonType:(json && json == "setup") ? PKPaymentButtonTypeSetUp : PKPaymentButtonTypeBuy];
}

- (UIView *)view
{
  return [PKPaymentButton style:PKPaymentButtonStyleWhiteOutline];
}
```